# No matching constructor while trying to call default constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, constructor

In my code I have a class with following structure:

```
 struct AutomatonNode {
    ...
    AutomatonNode();
    AutomatonNode(AutomatonNode &node);
    ...
};
```

Default constructor has following realisation:

```
AutomatonNode::AutomatonNode() :
    suffixLink(-1),
    len(0) {};
```

However, during compilation I get the following error:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'SA::AutomatonNode'

in this method:

```
size_t SuffixAutomaton::newState() {
    AutomatonNode node;
    nodes.push_back(node);
    return nodes.size() - 1;
}
```

Looks extremely strange to me, since everything is in place and the constructor is public(it's a struct and by default all fields are public). Any ideas?

For clearance:

Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0

Thread model: posix

Comment: Does it work if the copy constructor takes a const ref?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with default constructor. (What made you think it did?)

The problem is most likely caused by your copy constructor accepting its argument as *non-const* reference. (It is impossible to say for sure since you provided no information about what `nodes` is.) If `nodes` is a standard container, then standard `push_back` accepts its argument as a reference to const. Such argument cannot be passed to your copy constructor. Hence the error.